# restler: Multi-format issue on formats other than xml or json

Tags: php, restler, formats

I am having an issue with restler, although I registered the following formats:

```
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat','XmlFormat','YamlFormat','PlistFormat','AmfFormat');
```

formats other than JSON or xml are not routable using the suffix,

`/path/call.{suffix}` doesnt work at all except for .xml and .json, any ideas?

Using Restler v3 RC3

Comment: Wanted to add that with v2 everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Only JsonFormat and XmlFormat will work out of the box, remaining formats have external dependencies and require you to run `make composer-install` as explained in http://restler3.luracast.com under installation